# Plane curve transform to moving inertial system coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames

As a non-phycisist I hope my question makes sense and is understandable. It deals with special relativity. I suppose there is a e.g. plane curve ( e.g. a circle ) given in the x-y plane of of an inertial system with coordinates (t,x,y,z). If at time t=t'=0 there is a sync with a horizontally in the x-y plane moving inertial system with coordinates (t',x',y',z') I would like to know the more general transformation formulas to express the view/equation of the plane curve in the x'-y' plane of the moving system. The often published and derived formulas of the Lorentz transformation only deal with the 1-dimensional (t,x) case. A hint for a book which handles and derives (!) the general case would also be very helpful.
Please excuse if my question is nonsense - I would like to see ( by plotting ) how the e.g. circle changes in shape with t' time running seen/measured in the moving frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might help your cause (I don't have time to look at all your question), since you allege its lack in the literature. Your allegation implies a wish to dig into this kind of question seriously, so here are a couple of things you will need to learn to do so.

To work out the matrix for a general boost, simply take the matrix for a simply written down boost (*e.g.* an $x$-boost) and conjugate by a rotation matrix. That is:

$$\Lambda = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}1&\mathbf{0}\\\hline\mathbf{0}^T&R\end{array}\right)\,\left(\begin{array}{cccc}\cosh\eta&\sinh\eta&0&0\\\sinh\eta&\cosh\eta&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right)\,\left(\begin{array}{c|c}1&\mathbf{0}\\\hline\mathbf{0}^T&R^{-1}\end{array}\right)$$

where the $R$ is the $3\times3$ rotation matrix:

$$R=\exp\left(\theta\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&-\gamma_z&\gamma_y\\\gamma_z&0&-\gamma_x\\-\gamma_y&\gamma_x&0\end{array}\right)\right)$$

$\theta$ is the rotation angle and the $\gamma_j$ the direction cosines defining the rotation  axis ($\sum_k\gamma_k^2 = 1$).

Physically: rotate my co-ordinates to align them with the boost direction; impart the boost, then rotate my co-ordinates back to the original direction.

As you can see, this is quite a sizeable and messy expression. This kind of thing is much cleaner with spinor maps, where one represents position vectors of spacetime events by the Hermitian matrix:

$$X = t\,\mathrm{id} + x\,\sigma_x+y\,\sigma_y + z\,\sigma_z = \left(\begin{array}{cc}t+z&x-i\,y\\x+i\,y&t-z\end{array}\right)$$

where the $\sigma$s are the Pauli matrices and a general proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation is represented by an *arbitrary* $2\times2$ complex matrix $\Lambda$ with unit determinant and the action of the transformation on the position vector is calculated by:

$$X\mapsto \Lambda\,X\Lambda^\dagger$$

where $\dagger$ stands for complex conjugate transpose. In this notation, the matrix of a rotation is:

$$R = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\,\mathrm{id} + \frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\frac{\theta}{2}}\,\left(\begin{array}{cc}i\,\gamma_z&-\gamma_y+i\,\gamma_x\\\gamma_y+i\,\gamma_x&-i\,\gamma_z\end{array}\right) = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\,\mathrm{id} + i\,\frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\frac{\theta}{2}}\,\left(\gamma_x\,\sigma_x + \gamma_y\,\sigma_y+\gamma_z\,\sigma_z\right)$$

and that of a boost in the $z$ direction (note: not the $x$ direction as it was for the $4\times4$ matrix representation) is:

$$B_z=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\exp\left(\frac{\eta}{2}\right)&0\\0&\exp\left(-\frac{\eta}{2}\right)\end{array}\right)$$

See the Wikipedia article [Lorentz Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) (especially the big table therein) for more information. Again, the matrix for a general boost is calculated by conjugation: $R\,B\,R^{-1}$.

Comment: Allow to give you the points even though my interests now prevent me from checking my results with yours.

Answer (score 1):

You have not said the physics case you had in mind but if you are interested in figuring out how a static observer would see, with his eyes, a fast moving circle (by fast I mean its speed is a significant fraction of the speed of light), then a word of warning is in order, as a straightforward application of Lorentz transformations will give you the wrong answer. The key point is that it takes longer for the light to come to the observer eyes from the rear of the circle than from its front (rear and front as defined from the viewpoint of the observer). The result is that the static observer will not see an ellipse as a naive application of length contraction would give. It will look like [this movie](http://www.spacetimetravel.org/filme/radv_h_0.93/radv_h_0.93-xe-640x480.mpg) from [Kraus et al](http://www.spacetimetravel.org) website. Here is the description:

> The red wheel in the background is at rest, the green one is in stationary rotation (a point on the rim moves with a speed of 0.93c).
>   The shadows are due to a light source which illuminates the scene from a great distance from behind and above.
>   The blue wheel is rolling towards the observer (at a speed of 0.93c), from left to right.

The authors have plenty more stunning visualisations of relativistic objects. The mathematics and plenty of interesting references can be found in Kraus (2008). One of the oldest is Penrose (1959), in which the author showed that the outline of a moving  sphere would remain circular to the eyes of a static observer: the effect mentioned above exactly cancels length contraction in that case, a particularly dramatic illustration of the point I am trying to make.

Kraus (2008) U. Kraus, First-person visualizations of the special and general theory of relativity, Eur. J. Phys. 29 (2008) 1–13

Penrose (1959) Penrose R, Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc. 55 (1959) 137

Answer (score 0):

Length contraction is only in the direction parallel to the direction in which the observed body is travelling, that is why it is usually expressed in one dimension. In your case, the moving observer will see the length of the circle in the direction of motion is the only one that contracts, thus, in his reference frame, he will see an ellipse instead of a circle.

Comment: OK. What if the movement is along a line in the x-y plane ( e.g. 45 degree x=y or more general y=mx ) ?

Comment: the minor axis (the one that contracts) of the ellipse will change, it will be always parallel to the direction of motion (so, it will be an ellipse rotated 45 degrees if you draw it in the (x,y) plane

Comment: What I am looking for is now the transformation formula(s) needed to transform the $$x^2+y^2=1$$ to the ellpse equation(s) you talk about. Especially: is it true that the shape of the ellipse changes with t' time running ?

Comment: what do you mean by "with t' time running" ?

Comment: I calculate the ellipse (?) you talk about in this way. I use the transformation $x=\frac 1\gamma(x^\prime+vt^\prime)$ and $y=y^\prime$. When I plug into the circle equation I get $$(\frac 1\gamma(x^\prime+vt^\prime))^2+(y^\prime)^2=1$$ So first I dont see a stationary ellipse equation of the form $$\frac{(x^\prime)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y^\prime)^2}{b^2}=1$$ Second there is $t^\prime$ in the equation which is running in the sense of "ticking forward". So the shape is changing as I see it.

Comment: O I see, you equations seems fine, the shape of the ellipse will not change with t', only its position (it will move in the negative x' direction from your viewpoint). $a=\gamma$ does not change with t'

Comment: Ah now I understand. What interests me now is the way how to transform a curve $$f(x,y)=0$$ ( e.g an algebraic one ) into a form ( I suppose ) like $$g(t^\prime,x^\prime,y^\prime)=0$$ if the moving frame goes with velocity v in general direction $y=mx$. E.g. what would $g$ look like if $f$ is itself an ellipse ?